How do I manage a returned null value from a registry search, within a Try-Catch block? Getting 'You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression'
I'm trying to get the key name from a registry key, that has a property that matches certain text.
That key name will then be used to find the correct MSI file to run with MSIExec.exe to uninstall the software.
The following works as expected when there is a key found but fails when no key is found.
Try{
        $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
        $AlphaRegistry = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' | Where-Object{$_.DisplayName -like "*Alpha*"}
        switch ($AlphaRegistry.PSChildName.trim('{}')) {
            FB917EA8-1B7F-4347-A05F-7AF03DF0577D {$InstallerMSI = 'setup17_6.msi'}
            C75C2499-0D4D-6789-BEB2-32CA03BF8880 {$InstallerMSI = 'setup17_5.msi'}
            68C6A4F3-3422-467D-AAAA-924282DC5365 {$InstallerMSI = 'set17_4_1.msi'}
            
            Default {Add-LogContent "Unable to identify msi file to uninstall Alpha version installed.  Unable to progress"
                    [System.Environment]::Exit(1)}}

        # Uninstall code using $InstallerMSI here
}
catch{
    $ErrorMessage = "    Error during removal.  Unable to continue. " + $Error[0].Exception.Message
    Add-LogContent -LogText $ErrorMessage
    [System.Environment]::Exit(1)
}

I know I should test for null after $AlphaRegistry = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' | Where-Object{$_.DisplayName -like "*Alpha*"} but no matter what I try I can't get past that line.  I always get the error 'You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression'.  I don't even know what method is being called on that line.
I've tried taking the population of $AlphaRegistry out the equation and I still get the same error so know it isn't the assignment of null to the variable.
I've tried the same code outside the Try-Catch block and I don't get an error and therefore assume my implementation of the Try-Catch block is the cause.
I've also tried various settings for $ErrorActionPreference, both inside and before the Try-Catch block.
I want to use the error handling for the uninstall code I've removed, so ideally need a way to make the search work within the Try-Catch block.
Any pointer in the right direction would be appreciated thanks.

Are you sure that the error is on that line? My money's on the error coming from the next line when you try to call the .Trim() method. Would it really be so hard to add a If(!$AlphaRegistry){Write-Warning "App not found"; continue} before your switch?

I concur with the above comment. Although, I would go the route of if ($null -eq ($AlphaRegistry = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' | ? {$_.DisplayName -like "*Alpha*"})) { throw "No program found" }

@TheMadTechnician.  Thanks, after further testing you are correct, the next line is causing the issue.
When stepping through the code, the error is thrown when that line is moved onto, not when that line is executed.  That I think is strange behaviour, seen on both ISE & Visual Studio Code editors.
I'll work on a fix and post when proven.

If you are using PowerShell Core (v6.1+), you can use the Null-conditional operators (.?) like this $AlphaRegistry.PSChildName?.trim('{}').
switch ($AlphaRegistry.PSChildName?.trim('{}')) { <# ... #> }

If you are using Windows PowerShell, you can use an if statement wrapped in a subexpression $():
switch ($(if ($null -ne $AlphaRegistry.PSChildName) { $AlphaRegistry.PSChildName.trim('{}') })) { <# ... #> }

Or cast the object to a string by double quoting its value like this "$($AlphaRegistry.PSChildName)", and it works in both versions of PowerShell:
switch ("$($AlphaRegistry.PSChildName)".trim('{}')) { <# ... #> }


After testing I've settled on the following solution.  I like the simplicity of it and the fact that I end up with a string for the 'comparison' in the switch statement.
This way also allows me to make us of the Default in the switch for logging without additional lines of code.
An additional if statement is added prior to the uninstall process to accommodate null value in $AlphaRegistry
Thanks to all for your help.
Try{
    $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
    $AlphaRegistry = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' | Where-Object{$_.DisplayName -like "*Alpha*"}
    switch ("$($AlphaRegistry.PSChildName)".trim('{}')) {
        FB917EA8-1B7F-4347-A05F-7AF03DF0577D {$InstallerMSI = 'setup17_6.msi'}
        C75C2499-0D4D-6789-BEB2-32CA03BF8880 {$InstallerMSI = 'setup17_5.msi'}
        68C6A4F3-3422-467D-AAAA-924282DC5365 {$InstallerMSI = 'set17_4_1.msi'}
        
        Default {Add-LogContent "Unable to identify msi file to uninstall Alpha version installed.  Unable to progress"}
    }
enter code here
    if ($null -ne $AlphaRegistry) {
        # Uninstall code using $InstallerMSI here
    }
}
catch{
    $ErrorMessage = "    Error during removal.  Unable to continue. " + 
    $Error[0].Exception.Message
    Add-LogContent -LogText $ErrorMessage
    [System.Environment]::Exit(1)
}

